# If condition not working

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have a code in my **Perl** catalyst project

```
for (my $i=1; $i<=$periodsOrg; $i++){
    if ( $vals_repayment_org->{ending_balance} <= 0) {
        exit;
    }
}
```

ie; if `$vals_repayment_org->{ending_balance}` is less than or equal to 0, I need to exit from the loop.
But it exits from the loop in the first time itself but the value is not less than or equalto 0. The log I have got is

> EndBal: 249747.596957166
>
> Apr 29 05:55:43 [ERROR] ModPerl::Util::exit: (120000) exit was called
>   at
>   /home/wesolnsus/public_html/application/lib/wealthe/Controller/vbo/mortgage_reduction.pm
>   line 180

Comment: Which one is the value of `$vals_repayment_org->{ending_balance}` before `exit`? You may want to add a `print` statement before `exit` to output that value to make sure.

Comment: the value of $vals_repayment_org->{ending_balance} is  249747.596957166

Comment: @Jitesh put `use warnings; print $vals_repayment_org->{ending_balance} +0;` before `if` statement.

Comment: I have checked the value of $vals_repayment_org->{ending_balance} before IF condition, its 249747.596957166

Answer (score 3):

Calling `exit` terminates the *current process*.

To leave a loop, use `last`. Perl's loop control commands are called `last`, `next`, and `redo`.

Note further that in your code snippet, the outcome of

```
if ($vals_repayment_org->{ending_balance} <= 0) {
    exit;
}
```

is not affected by the loop variable `$i`, therefore the condition should be placed outside of the loop.

It is not conceivable that the condition evaluates to true if `$vals_repayment_org->{ending_balance}` is *larger* than zero – you'd have to provide further context to show this, e.g. like

```
my $ending_balance = $vals_repayment_org->{ending_balance};
if ($ending_balance <= 0) {
    warn "Ending Balance: $ending_balance";
    exit;
}
```

Further reading:

- [`exit` in perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html)
- [*Loop Control* in perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Loop-Control)